# Images doesn't upload in prestashop 1.6 using programmaticall csv upload

Tags: php, image, csv, upload, prestashop

I have 1.6.1.6 prestashop and I have a script to upload programatically csv file, all works fine except the images, it isn´t upload.

my script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());

include(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/../config/config.inc.php');

include(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/functions.php');

include_once '../controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php';

function loadProductsPost() {
$_POST = array (
'tab' => 'AdminImport',
'skip' => '1',
'csv' => 'conector.csv',
'forceIDs' => '0',
'match_ref' => '0',
'convert' => '',
'entity' => '1',
'separator' => ';',
'multiple_value_separator' => ',',
'iso_lang' => 'es',
'import' => 'Importar datos CSV',
'type_value' =>
    array (

0 => 'no',
1 => 'active',
2 => 'name',
3 => 'category',
4 => 'price_tin',
5 => 'id_tax_rules_group',
6 => 'reference',
7 => 'manufacturer',
8 => 'quantity',
9 => 'minimal_quantity',
10 => 'description_short',
11 => 'description',
12 => 'tags',
13 => 'meta_title',
14 => 'meta_keywords',
15 => 'meta_description',
16 => 'link_rewrite',
17 => 'available_now',
18 => 'available_for_order',
19 => 'date_add',
20 => 'show_price',
21 => 'image',
22 => 'delete_existing_images',
23 => 'online_only',
24 => 'condition',
25 => 'customizable',
26 => 'uploadable_files',
27 => 'text_fields',
28 => 'out_of_stock',
29 => 'shop',

    ),
  );
}

$import = New AdminImportController();

    loadProductsPost();

    $import->productImport();

    var_dump($import);


?>
```

There are no errors in the log, I have allowed all permissions in img folder. My .csv is right and columns are right. My script is located in /admin folcer, all includes are right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: images are full link with href://www.yourstore.com/images-import/products/product_id_1.jpg,href://www.yourstore.com/images-import/products/product_id_2.jpg, etc or just /images-import/products/product_id_1.jpg, /images-import/products/product_id_2.jpg? If yes try to use full href links to images

Comment: there are like this `http://domain.com/productos/big-158936.jpg`